# Appending images to a div of custom height and width with Javascript only works with set dimensions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I am trying to pull the front page of Reddit using a HTTP GET request and then display a web page that consists of just the images from the thumbnail.

Here is the code so far I have that succesfully gets the image's URL and image dimensions. After I get the information I need for each one I am trying to create a new div element and append it to the gridArticle element I get by ID. Before doing so I am updating its class name as well as image and size.

```
 $.getJSON("https://www.reddit.com/.json", function (data) {
    var items = [];
    $.each(data.data.children, function (i, obj) {
        if ((obj.data.preview != null) && (obj.data.preview.images != null)) {

            var imageSourceUrl = preview.images[0].source.url;
            var height = preview.images[0].source.height;
            var width = preview.images[0].source.width;

           var listingEntry = document.createElement("div");
            listingEntry.className = "tile";
            listingEntry.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + imageSourceUrl + ")";
            listingEntry.style.width = width
            listingEntry.style.height = height;



            var gridArticle = document.getElementById("gridArticle");
            gridArticle.appendChild(listingEntry);

        }
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<article id="gridArticle">


  </article>
```

CSS

```
   article .tile {

    display: block;
    float: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;

    font-size: 3em;
    font-weight: 700;

    padding: 0 6px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black;

    border:1px dotted black;
  }
```

However if I remove the background-size property and in the parent article .tile{} add the height and width property's there and set them to a fixed length (100 px 100 px for example) the images show up fine but just at the specified dimensions.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding the images to the divs you're inserting as backgrounds. As such they're behaving entirely as you would expect - if a div has no content then it won't occupy any space therefore you aren't going to see any background. Setting a background size won't affect the dimensions of the div itself.

Solutions:

1. Take your existing height and width variables in JS and apply them as CSS height and width. You won't need to bother setting a background size; in CSS make the size 'cover'.
2. Use real image elements instead of backgrounds on a div.

Comment: Edited the original post with the update code I just ran: I simplified the CSS all as one for simplification and removed the width and height properties. Then in the JS file I set the width and height there but this has not solved the issue. Trying adding them as <img> now

Answer (score 0):

Your `div.tile.image` elements don't have any content, nor do they have a set `width` and `height`, which causes blocks to occupy no space at all (you can verify this using your browser's inspector tool).

One way to fix this would be setting the `width` and `height` of your elements:

```
listingEntry.style.width = width;
listingEntry.style.height = height;
```

The other would be to add your images as `img` elements appended to your `tile` and set the `display` property of your `tile` to `inline-block`.